# How do you change the state of buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am building an android which allows the user to select one of two options; I tried using RadioGroup but couldn't reflect my design with it so I had to drop that, I tried using drawable's selectors which my friend suggested but even that didn't work. Now I thought of changing the state of the other button when one is clicked, but couldn't find any meaningful suggestions.
Can you help out?

**[Here is a picture of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9xCk.png)**

Comment: Have a look at [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site. Please note that this site isn't a replacement for other great online resources like tutorials or books when learning something. Please show us your attempts to solve this problem yourself (= your coding), with that you have a good basis to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:clickable`

and

`xButton.setEnabled(false);`

I suggest you try.
Clicking the selected button, you can change the status of the other.

Answer (score 0):

in Java:

```
yourButton.setClickable(false);
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
```

in Kotlin:

```
yourButton.clickable = false
yourButton.enabled = false
```

Comment: do I need to call both the methods?

Comment: the enabled attribute takes care of it, I also use clickable, but maybe it's not necessary.